# parse mysql error msg - is it the right way?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysql-error-1062

In my php/MySQL code I insert new record into a table (InnoDB) which has many UNIQUE column keys. If insertion fails (with ER_DUP_ENTRY) I **need** to know which column's value wasn't unique.

I was told that to achieve this, you must extract value of %d from error message you get: 
*"Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d".*

This should work but I don't like the solution. Parsing/regex matching some string gives unnecessary complexity to simple task I always try to avoid. Now the question: is this the right way to go? Isn't there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably possible to not get just the error message but also the corresponding error code too. See for example the [results for PHP functions containing `errno`](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=errno).

Comment: I meant error message not error code. I've changed the subject.

Comment: @spajak: I guess there is no other way of doing that. But you could try `sscanf` as the inverse of `sprintf`.